$\Delta U$ (a state function (partially)), behaving as a path function. How?
I've just completed Thermodynamics in high school. They say $\Delta U$ is a state function, and so is $\Delta H$. But then, see when we follow different paths:

Isothermal,
Isochoric,
Isobaric,
Adiabatic.

We get different values of $\Delta U$ and $\Delta H$ for each. Why?

Please, add some detail about your doubts. I guess that this question is likely to be closed since it doesn't meet the minimum "quality standard" for a question. Voting to close, glad to answer a better question later.

These paths don't lead you to the same result. If you compress a monoatomic ideal gas adiabatically, you give it energy by the work you're doing, thus elevating its temperature. However, compressing it isothermally means it is coupled to a heat bath with constant temperature, and all of the extra energy you gave the gas by compressing it went to the heat bath (to keep a constant temperature). These two paths are different not only in energy but also in temperature, and pressure (by $PV=nRT$ and $E= 3/2 \, nRT$).
In conclusion, these paths give you different energies because they take you to different states.
Hope this helped!
